# magento fail to send email due to spam detection

Tags: email, magento, smtp, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I have hosted my site on hostgator and created mail id from there, like admin@mysite.com.I am using smtp pro config as
 **custom smtp,login,host:admin@webnet.com,port 462 ,ssl.**

In sales email -order i have given 
New Order Confirmation Email Sender sales rep.admin@mysite.com
**Send Order Email Copy To: admin@mysite.com**

But after order when i checked my mail it show order copy to admin@mysite.com
because of bcc but doesn't delivered to customer.
email bounce back saying

**Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender**
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

This message from admin@mysite.com, Subject:

```
 your order from  mobile , with RefID: `str=0001.0A150208.54C8FE77.00BF,ss=4,sh,re=0.000,recu=0.000,reip=0.000,cl=4,cld=1,`
```

**fgs=520 was rejected due to classification as CONFIRMED SPAM.**

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

I think my server's IP is considered or blocked by gmail and yahoo mail due to spamming????????

solution is to move  outgoing mail (SMTP) via services like mailgun??????

Comment: Check this and also for sending email we should enable cron services in magento http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/everything-email/spam-prevention-techniques/550-spam-message

Answer (score 0):

**Your server mail is considering SPAMMER because it's not properly set up!**

Test if your server isn't open mail relay, if the sender's or server's IP address isn't blacklisted. Look if the server does not have a Fully Qualified Domain Name (**FQDN**) and a PTR record.

> Install Sender Policy Framework (**SPF**) DNS record 
>   & Install DomainKeys Identified Mail (**DKIM**) implementation in Server and DNS

*for DKIM key, look opendkim and opendkim-tools documentation.*